# run regex against 3rd column only

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Using this regular expression, I'm finding a string of numbers starting with 9, followed by 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 9, followed by 6 more numbers.

```
9*[45679]( *[0-9]){6}
```

I have a file named content.txt containing 3 columns. The first column is a date, the second a time and the third contains random text and numbers with spaces in it.

```
20/10/2022 19:00 test 1 99 435 18 1 more text
20/10/2022 20:00 test 2 97 123 1 81 more text2
20/10/2022 21:00 test 3 96 4 3 5567 more text3
20/10/2022 22:00 test 4 99 43 5181 more text4
```

Using my regular expression I want to modify the third column and leave only the results of the regular expression, with no spaces, so the result should be

```
20/10/2022 19:00 99435181
20/10/2022 20:00 97123181
20/10/2022 21:00 96435567
20/10/2022 22:00 99435181
```

the field separator is a space

Comment: The regex `9*[45679]( *[0-9]){6}` does not match your description. The `9*` matches zero or more `9`s, followed by a `4`, `5`, `6` or `7`. The ` *` (space asterisk) can match zero spaces. Thus `( *[0-9]){6}` can match any sequence of six digits with spaces in any place.

Comment: The regex `9*[45679]( *[0-9]){6}` will match both `5 8 8 8 8 8 8` and `6888888` which do not match the description, neither has a `9`.

Comment: any suggestions for a better regex?

Comment: @aristosv, You have already got few answers, request you to kindly do check them all and reply to each answerer so that they will be aware what's working and what's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **GNU** sed. I assume your field separator is one space.

```
sed -E 's/^(.{16}).*( 9[45679]( *[0-9]){6}).*/\1\2/; s/ //g3' file
```

Output:

```
20/10/2022 19:00 99435181
20/10/2022 20:00 97123181
20/10/2022 21:00 96435567
20/10/2022 22:00 99435181
```

See: `man sed`

Comment: eventually I ended up using this

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU awk, one option is to use the `gensub()` function, e.g.

```
gawk '{
    a = gensub(/.*(9[45679] [0-9 ]{6,}).*/, "\\1", "g", $0) #extract the numbers and spaces
    gsub(/ /, "", a) #remove the spaces
    print $1, $2, a 
}' test.txt
20/10/2022 19:00 99435181
20/10/2022 20:00 97123181
20/10/2022 21:00 96435567
20/10/2022 22:00 99435181
```

---

And this should work with other (i.e. non-GNU) awks (tested with mawk v1.3.4 20200120):

```
awk '
match($0, / 9[45679] [0-9 ]+/) { #match the regex
    a = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1) #extract the numbers and spaces
    gsub(/ /, "", a) # remove the spaces
    print $1, $2, a
}' test.txt
20/10/2022 19:00 99435181
20/10/2022 20:00 97123181
20/10/2022 21:00 96435567
20/10/2022 22:00 99435181
```

Answer (score 4):

In GNU `awk` with your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Here is the working [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GtaOxI/1) for used regex.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/^([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})\s+([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(\s+\S+){2}\s+([0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]*).*/,arr){
  gsub(/ +/,"",arr[4])
  print arr[1],arr[2],arr[4]
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for used regex.

```
^(                                   ##Matching from starting of the value and opening 1st capturing group.
  [0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}       ##Matching 2 digits followed by / followed by 2 digits / and followed by 4 digits.
)                                    ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
\s+                                  ##Matching 1 or more spaces here.
(                                    ##Opening 2nd capturing group here.
  [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}                  ##Matching 2 digits followed by colon followed by 2 digits.
)                                    ##Closing 2nd capturing group here.
(\s+\S+){2}                          ##In 3rd capturing group matching spaces followed by non-spaces matching 2 occurrences of this group.
\s+                                  ##Matching 1 or more spaces.
(                                    ##Opening 4th capturing group here.
  [0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]*  ##Matching digits followed by spaces followed by digits folllowed by spaces followed by digits followed by digits followed by spaces followed by Optional digits.
)                                    ##Closing 4th capturing group here.
.*                                   ##Matching everything till end of value here.
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^((\S+ ){2})(\S+ ){2}(9[45679]( ?[0-9]){6}) .*/{s//\1\4/;s/ //3g}' file
```

Use pattern matching and back references to format as required.

N.B. This solution leaves unmatched lines as is. To delete non matching lines use:

```
sed -nE '/^((\S+ ){2})(\S+ ){2}(9[45679]( ?[0-9]){6}) .*/{s//\1\4/;s/ //3g;p}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

As we don't know what the delimiters are, and assuming that the number of interest has only one occurrence after the time,  you might use 2 capture groups using `gnu awk`, and use those groups in the replacement where you would remove all spaces in group 2.

See the [regex group captures](https://regex101.com/r/BUXUmt/1).

```
awk 'match($0, /(.*\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s+).*(9[4-9]( *[0-9]){6})/, a) {
  print a[1] gensub(/ +/, "", "g", a[2])
}' content.txt
```

Output

```
20/10/2022 19:00 99435181
20/10/2022 20:00 97123181
20/10/2022 21:00 96435567
20/10/2022 22:00 99435181
```

If your field separator is for example a tab:

```
awk -F"\t" 'match($3, /(9[4-9]( *[0-9]){6})/, a) {
  print $1, $2, gensub(/ +/, "", "g", a[1])
}' content.txt
```